# How to use dojox tools in DoJo?

Tags: dojo

I am now learning Dojo. So I want to build my first demo by how to use gauges in Dojo.
I downloaded the zip package and build an asp.net web project. then all the resources from Dojo package are imported to this project.

Because I saw the demo from DoJo website: http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/gauges/demo.html, So I want to copy this demo in my local computer with existing DoJo resources.
HTML code below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DojoDaemon.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Dojo Circular Gauge Test  Daemon</title>
<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"  data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
<script src="Scripts/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/dgauges/components/black/CircularLinearGauge.js"
    type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
<script src="Scripts/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/dgauges/components/black/HorizontalLinearGauge.js"
    type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
<script src="Scripts/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/dgauges/components/black/SemiCircularLinearGauge.js"
    type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server" id="form1">
<h2 align="center" style="color:white;">Predefined Glossy Gauges</h2>
<table style="height:100%; width:100%">
         <tr>
    <td align="center">
    <div id="CircularGauge" background="{color:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}" useTooltip="false" data-dojo-type="Scripts/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/dgauges/components/black/CircularLinearGauge" style="width:200px;height:200px" value="20"></div></td>
    <td align='center'>
    <div id="CircularGauge2" background="{color:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}" useTooltip="false"  data-dojo-type="Scripts/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/dgauges/components/black/SemiCircularLinearGauge" value="10" style="width:250px;height:200px"></div></td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
     <td valign="middle" align="center" colspan="2">
    <div id="HGauge3" style="margin:30px 0px 0px 0px;width:400px;height:60px" useTooltip="false" background="{color:'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}"  data-dojo-type="Scripts/dojo-release-1.9.1/dojox/dgauges/components/black/HorizontalLinearGauge" value="20"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
 </html>
```

Above is the code I use, I have searched a lot of examples, but got nothing because no one article give me the detailed steps to teach me how to use the resources in dojox folder.
resources I found like :
http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/dgauges/CircularGauge
http://dmandrioli.github.io/dgauges/dojox/dgauges/CircularGauge.html
Would anyone help me if familar with this? thank you ver much.

Comment: you also need parseOnLoad: true in data-dojo-config.  Also usually you just load the dojo.js with the script tag, the other libraries are loaded using the require function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to load dojo.js in the src and the [src.js](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/gauges/src.js) which they have included for the demo. Click on the View Source of http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/gauges/demo.html and copy the code exactly!

Dojo can seem like a beast at first, but its a beautiful toolkit that you will come to love and appreciate. Give it time. I STRONGLY recommend you say [Hi to Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/) before jumping to dguage and other advanced stuff.