# How to develop dojox data grid table

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dojox.grid

I want to develop grid table using dojox toolkit as shown [here](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/grid/demo.html).
I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782497/how-to-use-dojox-tools-in-dojo) but did not worked for me.
I want to have dojox grid table in static html page with explicit import of all css and js files.
I have done this for jqGrid tables but not able to do for dojox grid table.
Added dojo.css,claro.cssclaroGrid.css,Grid.css,dojo.js resources in html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Demo: dojox.grid.DataGrid View's defaultCell</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dojo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/claro.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/claroGrid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/Grid.css">

        <script src="./js/dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
<script>
    dojo.require('dojox.grid.DataGrid');
    dojo.require('dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore');
    dojo.require('dijit.form.Button');
var itemList = [
        {alienPop: 320000,humanPop: 56000,planet: 'Zoron'},
        {alienPop: 980940,humanPop: 56052,planet: 'Gaxula'},
        {alienPop: 200,humanPop: 500,planet: 'Reiutsink'},
        ];

        dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    var itemList = [
        {alienPop: 320000,humanPop: 56000,planet: 'Zoron'},
        {alienPop: 980940,humanPop: 56052,planet: 'Gaxula'},
        {alienPop: 200,humanPop: 500,planet: 'Reiutsink'},
        ];

    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: {
            identifier : 'planet',

            items: itemList
        }
    });


    grid.setStore(store);

    });
    </script>
            <table id="myDataGrid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" style="width:400px;">
        <thead>
        <tr><th field="planet" width="33%">Planet</th>
            <th field="alienPop" width="33%">Aliens</th>
            <th field="humanPop" width="33%">Humans</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some of you code ans try to refine your question. Thanks!

Comment: @dkb add the code in your question body. Not in comments. No one is gonna read it in comments

Comment: @NSNoob, thanks, done
Refer this page: jsfiddle.net/bhagat_dineshbe2006/th3fuek9, it works on IE. static html page it is not working.

Comment: Found another example with php page: https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/datagrid/demo/datagrid-simple.php

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on dojo documentation for Grid.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#examples

Look at the first example. It is creating a simple Data Grid programmatically.